# How to Create Custom PushButton in QT5.6.1

Tags: qt, widget, qt5, qpushbutton

I am very new to QT development. Can anyone share "How to create a custom QPushButton in QT" so that custom button will have same behavior as of QPushButton only differ from custom properties. So please any clue or any direction to this will be helpful. 
I have tried for the Analog Clock example which is given in QT custom widget example. But I didn't find related with QPushbutton. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) First of all you have to start from subclassing a qpusbutton class. 2)Than you have to use google to find this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=whgZ0iKztIo)

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple. First you need to subclass QPushButton. Add your methods to enhance it. And you are done.

For example, I have written CustomButton which have an extra method to reverse the text.

CustomButton.h

```
#ifndef CUSTOMBUTTON_H
#define CUSTOMBUTTON_H

#include <QPushButton>

class CustomButton : public QPushButton
{
public:
    CustomButton( const QString& text, QWidget* parent = 0 );

    // Enhancement, it will reverse the button text
    void reverseText();
};

#endif // CUSTOMBUTTON_H
```

CustomButton.cpp

```
#include "CustomButton.h"
#include "algorithm"

CustomButton::CustomButton( const QString& text, QWidget* parent )
    : QPushButton( text, parent )
{

}

void CustomButton::reverseText()
{
    QString buttonText = text();
    std::reverse(buttonText.begin(), buttonText.end());
    setText( buttonText );
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "CustomButton.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    CustomButton w( "MyButton" );
    w.show();
    w.reverseText();
    a.exec();
    return 0;
}
```

The button looks like this
[image]

If you want to do something related to look and feel.
Instead of creating custom button you can use [QStyleSheet](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet.html)

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I will be more appreciated if you explain/suggest how to use this custom button as new widget plugin and call in other project with all its custom methods say in this case reverse method.

Comment: It will behave like any other widget. What do you mean by Plugin? are you talking about QtCreator Designer plugin?

Comment: Yes, QtCreator Designer Plugin that too using painter class for creating button and not using StyleSheet.